# Comparison of Expectation of two vector of random variable.

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, expectation

Let $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be two vector of positive random variables where all components are independent (either uniform or positive Gaussian).

If $\mathbf{1}_n^T\mathbf{x}$>$\mathbf{1}_n^T\mathbf{y}$, what can be said about comparison of $\mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}_n^T\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}]$ and $\mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}_n^T\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y}]$?

Comment: What is 'positive Gaussian'?

Comment: think of it as absolute value of some Gaussian random variables ;)

Comment: @questioner, is there a particular property/relationship you are interested in?

Comment: that whether or not, the first one is greater than the second one.